# Gererating report ondemand to a directory

Tags: reporting-services

Normally people need to view report on report viewer.
But I need to just generate report in a directory.

What should i do for this?

Comment: Check out the MSDN info on reporting services http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa179578%28SQL.80%29.aspx there may be something in there to help you.  Since you want to generate the report in a directory I expect you will want to call SSRS have it generate then export the report as PDF or other format to a directory of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SSRS built-in subscriptions to write to a directory/fileshare. With Enterprise edition, you could use data-driven subscriptions to write the report out only when needed by some other criteria.

But to truly make this on demand, then you'll need to do a little bit of coding. The simplest method is just to retrieve the filestream from a request created using URL Access and write that to a file.

Just throwing together a sample that will give the general idea:

```
string sTargetURL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportingServicesURL"]
   + "/ProductReports/ProductDetails&rs:Command=Render&rs:format=PDF&ProductID=" + ProductID;

HttpWebRequest req =
   (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create( sTargetURL );
req.PreAuthenticate = true;
// req.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential( strReportUser, strReportUserPW, strReportUserDomain );

HttpWebResponse HttpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();


using (var fileStream = File.Create("C:\\Path\\To\\File"))
{
    HttpWResp.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(fileStream);
}

HttpWResp.Close();
```